# R - How can I color and label the max and min values points of my scatterplot using ggplot2?

Tags: r, label, scatter-plot, points, minimax

I have a simple data.frame (`piez_df`) with 2 columns (`Fecha` Vs `E.N.E.`):

```
   Fecha  E.N.E.
1   1993 1871.40
2   1994      NA
3   1995 1869.40
4   1996 1866.85
5   1997 1857.94
6   1998 1849.43
7   1999 1849.59
8   2000 1858.61
9   2001 1850.30
10  2002 1852.50
11  2003      NA
12  2004 1850.70
13  2005      NA
14  2006 1850.80
15  2007 1850.82
16  2008      NA
17  2009 1832.30
18  2010      NA
19  2011      NA
20  2012      NA
21  2013      NA
22  2014      NA
23  2015      NA
24  2016      NA
25  2017      NA
26  2018 1809.30
27  2019 1809.30
28  2020 1808.70
```

I'm using `ggplot()` and I want to make a scatter plot with the max and min values of `E.N.E.` colored in red and blue respectively, aside I want to label this two points with its respective `Fecha` & `E.N.E.` values (one below the other).

This has been my best try:

```
ggplot(data = piez_df, aes(x = Fecha, y = E.N.E.)) +
      geom_point(color="black", size=2) +
      geom_point(data = piez_df[which.min(piez_df$E.N.E.), ], color="blue", 
                 size=3) +
      geom_point(data = piez_df[which.max(piez_df$E.N.E.), ], color="red", 
                 size=3)
```

[Scatter plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqlom.png)

I am new to R and have already spent a few days wondering how to do it, but still haven't been able to add the tags the way I want. Hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. I suggest to add the text using `geom_text()` as follows:

```
cars$lab <- paste(cars$speed,cars$dist, sep="\n")

ggplot(data = cars, aes(x = speed, y = dist)) +
    geom_point(color="black", size=2) +
    geom_point(data = cars[which.min(cars$dist), ], color="blue", 
               size=3) +
    geom_point(data = cars[which.max(cars$dist), ], color="red", 
               size=3) +
    geom_text(data = rbind(cars[which.min(cars$dist), ], cars[which.max(cars$dist),]), aes(speed+1,dist, label=lab))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @pascal. This works for me, i just change `geom_text()` for `geom_text_repel()` to adjust the label position. I still have a lot to learn. Do you know how to edit this part: `paste(cars$speed,cars$dist, sep="\n")`, so i can add the units after each value avoiding the line brake, e.g. (`paste(cars$speed+"mph",cars$dist+"mi", sep="\n")`).

Comment: Without too much thinking an easy solution is to use nested paste commands: `cars$lab <- paste(paste(cars$speed,"mph"),paste(cars$dist,"mi"), sep="\n")`

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of achieving this, depending on the output you want to generate. In the case of `ggplot2` you can use either `geom_text` or `geom_label`. If you want two pieces of data to show up, the best way I'd say is to first combine them, but you could make two calls to either function passing each column as the `label`

```
library(magrittr)

piez_df <- tibble::tribble(
   ~year, ~ene,
   1993, 1871.40,
   1994, NA,
   1995, 1869.4,
   1996, 1866.85,
   1997, 1857.94,
   1998, 1849.43,
   1999, 1849.59,
   2000, 1858.61,
   2001, 1850.30,
   2002, 1852.5,
   2003, NA,
   2004, 1850.7
) %>% 
   dplyr::mutate(
      plot_text = glue::glue("{year}\n{ene}")
   )

ggplot2::ggplot(
   data = piez_df,
   ggplot2::aes(
      x = year,
      y = ene
   )
) +
   ggplot2::geom_point(
      color = "black",
      size = 2
   ) +
   ggplot2::geom_point(
      data = piez_df[base::which.min(piez_df[["ene"]]),],
      color = "blue",
      size = 3
   ) +
   ggplot2::geom_point(
      data = piez_df[base::which.max(piez_df[["ene"]]), ],
      color = "red",
      size = 3
   ) +
   ggplot2::geom_text(
      data = piez_df[base::which.min(piez_df[["ene"]]),],
      ggplot2::aes(
         label = plot_text
      ),
      check_overlap = TRUE,
      nudge_y = 2
   ) +
   ggplot2::geom_label(
      data = piez_df[base::which.max(piez_df[["ene"]]),],
      ggplot2::aes(
         label = plot_text
      )
   )
```

The `geom_label` function can be used to replace the point with the actual label, while the `geom_text` function adds the text to the plot. By default, the text will be positioned using the original `x` and `y` coordinates in your data, so be sure to nudge it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Daniel. I ran your code and got an acceptable plot, is different from my former plot due to the lack of data inside `tribble()` and as you said, it needs to be nudge it. Why do I must use `tribble()` and redefine my former dataframe with different column names (`~year`, `~ene`)? Since I got to do this kind of plot for a lot of different samples, I want to avoid this last and use my former dataframe and column names. Is it possible?

Comment: @JorgeMona you don't need to redefine your df. I created one based on the original image that you posted. I just a `tribble` because I was going to enter the values by hand one at a time. As to your questions about the column names, there's no standard that one MUST follow, but for every language, there are style guides that the community tends to follow. You can read all about R's `tidyverse` style guide [here](https://style.tidyverse.org/)

Comment: Keep in mind that the name that the column has in the `df` is not necessarily the one that will be displayed on your plots or tables. For example, if you want the labels to show the formatted names of the columns, you could use `df %>% dplyr::mutate(plot_text = glue::glue("Fecha: {year}\nE.N.E: {ene}"))`